# Merge ImageCollections with different pixel size

Tags: google-earth-engine, merge, landsat-8, sentinel-2, resampling

I want to combine 2 different Image Collections (i.e. Landsat8 and Sentinel-2), and I want to combine them to a unique ImageCollection (and then run the function `qualityMosaic()`).
However, they have different pixel size and I think that is giving me the error. I tried resampling but it does not work:

```
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')

var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')

var resample = function (image){
  return image.resample('bilinear').reproject({
    crs: L8.first().projection().crs(),
    scale: 20
})}

var L8 = L8.map(resample)

var S2 = S2.map(resample)

var collection = L8.merge(S2)
Map.addLayer(collection)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: could you share the errors as well.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the pixel size. GEE is saying that your images in `collection` has different band profiles between images (i.e. number of bands, band name, data type of each band).

Comment: Indeed, that is fixed by resampling. I´d have to retitle "with different characteristics"

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by converting every image to integer 16. As @Kevin posted, collections have different band profiles.

Solution is:

```
var resample = function (image){
return image.int16().resample('bilinear').reproject({
crs: L8.first().projection().crs(),
scale: 20
```